# how to push project from local machine on windows 10 to github repo

Tags: git, ssh

I did a git init in folder on my laptop

`/c/Users/user1/user2/Lab assignments/mtech project/tex files/Thesis_8_March`

now I did a git init in this directory I see a .git folder created and a file name config

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:kiotie32/kiotie32.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
~
```

how do I tell git that I want to push all the folders and files on that particular folder 
to  repo to which I want to push ,Here is a link to
https://github.com/users/kiotie32/projects/2
what command should I issue and set things upto.

[image: no repository]
I have created a project not repository from Github in the browser.
if you see in above screenshot what I get is a project page it does not give me any link to something like repo.git to which I can issue git remote command like

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

I have previously uploaded projects hence this is not a new thing for me. In this case you see the screenshot and then let me know what needs to be done?

Comment: Github also has their own help docs: [Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line). You might want to check it out.

Comment: I have created a project not repository from Github in the browser. if you see in above screenshot what I get is a project page it does not give me any link to something like repo.git to which I can issue git remote command. I have added a screenshot of how it appears to me and why I asked this question.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion of terms here: a git repo != github project. What you have on your local machine is a git repo. To push that to Github, you first need to create a Github repo, then push that (follow the duplicate link). [Project Boards](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards) are a Github concept, **not** a git concept, don't confuse it with git commands. After pushing your git repo to Github, you can now [link it to your project](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-repository-to-a-project-board).

Comment: ok you mean to say I should create repositories for the folders which I have on my local machine and then treat them as git repo and do the commands to upload them to repositories.

Comment: It depends on how you plan to organize/manage your codes and the Github project. But, yes, something like that: you need to create local **git repositories** (for each folder or contains all the folders, up to you), push that to Github, then link the repo/s to the Github project.

Comment: Ok thanks for this information I was not able to understand I thought projects are same as repositories.