# how to push project from local machine on windows 10 to github repo version 1.1

Tags: git

I did a git init in folder on my laptop

`/c/Users/user1/user2/Lab assignments/mtech project/tex files/Thesis_8_March`

now I did a git init in this directory I see a .git folder created and a file name config

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:kiotie32/kiotie32.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
~
```

how do I tell git that I want to push all the folders and files on that particular folder 
to  repo to which I want to push ,Here is a link to
https://github.com/users/kiotie32/projects/2
what command should I issue and set things upto.

[image: no repository]
I have created a project not repository from Github in the browser.
if you see in above screenshot what I get is a project page it does not give me any link to something like repo.git to which I can issue git remote command like

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

I have previously uploaded projects hence this is not a new thing for me. In this case you see the screenshot and then let me know what needs to be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to push project from local machine on windows 10 to github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586461/how-to-push-project-from-local-machine-on-windows-10-to-github-repo)

Comment: I read that link in that link it says to create a new repo if you see the screenshot I posted above I do not get any option to create a repo inside the project. I have a lot of different different codes I want them to be in different different projects and separate repository for all of them. So I created one new project and inside that I do not see an option to create a repository.

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't ask the second question work-to-word identical to the first. You'd better [edit] and explain in what way the linked answer doesn't answer your needs.

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, a project and a repository are two different things.  A repository, which is a term that comes from Git, holds your code.  A project board is a set of issues or other cards on a board for managing what work is in progress and what work needs to be done.  This can be associated with a repository or not.

If you just want to store your code, ignore the Projects tab.  Instead, go to the Repositories tab that you can see to the left of it in your picture.  If you already have a repository for your code, you can find a link to it there.  If you need to create a new repository, there should be a button to do so there.